# Scaled image does not appear correctly until Frame is resized

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, paint

I am trying to scale an image with AffineTransform.  However, the image does not appear correctly when the Frame appears initially.

[image]

But after the frame is resized, the image shows perfectly.

[image]

Here is the code.

```
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  Line line;
  BufferedImage bi;

  public MainFrame() {
    initComponents();

    try {
      bi = ImageIO.read(new File("map.png"));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    AffineTransform old = g2.getTransform();
    g2.scale(0.25, 0.25);
    g2.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
    g2.setTransform(old);
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Could be that your `Graphics` is already clipped to the bounds of the component. If scaling, you might also need to scale the clip bounds.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556). 3) `g2.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);` should be `g2.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, this);` and the first thing the overridden paint should do is call the `super` method.

Comment: this could be proper way for ImageObserver, then JFrame isn't proper container for any Graphics Whatever, use JPanel with paintComponent, no idea without your SSCCE / MCVE / MCTRE